# Restricted HTTP requests to web server from Android

Tags: java, php, android, http

In the application I am currently working on, I need to implement a way to restrict an HTTP POST request to upload media to the server.

I already have registration implemented so is the best way to do this to send a `Basic authentication` header with every request?

I have no interest in implementing any kind of DRM in my app, so it doesn't matter if the request came from my app or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use  HTTP BASIC authentication along with **HTTPS** in every request. Every kind of data is entirely encrypted and web services are secured with authentication.

Comment: Yes, I eventually plan to do everything over HTTPS. What I am getting at is: Is it necessary to process an Authorization header with every request?

Comment: I suppose yes, because if you use rest API you haven't a session. In Android you can implement a single function/class that helps and creates a header. Just use this function/class before firing the post. If you open, for example, a single URLConnection or a HTTPClient at every request, you need to add the basic auth header.